# How do I set up Xcode source control so that my repository can be accessed by two MacBooks?

Tags: xcode, git

I have managed to set up `Source Control` locally on my MacBook (let's call it MacBook1) without any problems.

I would like to set up another MacBook (MacBook2) to access the same repository (the one stored locally on MacBook1). Basically I want both machines to be able to work on the same project at the same time and use MacBook1 as the Git repository and source control server (for lack of a better term).

I've tried clicking on my Wi-Fi status icon and `Create Network`, but when I do this I can no longer access the internet through Wi-Fi. Also my `Git` folder for my project is a hidden folder and I cannot seem to select it for sharing.

How can I share my MacBook1 local Git repository across 2 machines?

Comment: You could just put the repository on http://github.com and then access it from either Mac?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and that's a good idea, but I would like to keep this as private as possible, and local if possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the repo private then use [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/), however if you want to make it public then use [github.com](https://github.com/).

I use bitbucket even though I only generally use one Mac for development as I figure their data handling standards are better than mine and I am less likely to lose data due to disk crashes etc.

You basically create an empty repo on bitbucket and then in your local working repo, do:

```
$ git remote add origin https://bitbucket.org/YourName/YourRepo.git
$ git push --all
$ git push --tags
```

(I am not associated with Atlassian).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that bitbucket allows private repos. From your experience, how secure is a bitbucket private repo?

Comment: @PaulG Well I've no cause to be alarmed, but I cannot tell you who has access to my source code, however I am confident that if customers did start to smell leaks it would damage Atlassian's reputation considerably.